# wxWidgets (wxRuby) with Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, ruby-2.0, wxruby

I'm looking for an Win32 wxRuby gem for Ruby 2.0, does someone know where to find it? I didn't have success trying to build it and it seems the project is dead.

Comment: What does "I didn't have success trying to build it" mean? Did it fail during the build? Did it build but not work? Show the pertinent lines if there were errors. As is, you didn't show much to help you with, other than possible search-engine results, which you should have already done as part of your due-diligence.

Comment: @theTinMan I used DevKit from RubyInstaller and I have problems and errors building Wx, Swig and Wxruby. As it is a really complex thing and I have an application on production, I didn't want to spend time testing and debbuging it. I know it is not the right "study approaching" but need to focus on my app dev, not Wxruby library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest ruby version which supports wxruby gem is 1.9.1 (gem is named wxruby-ruby19, gem named wxruby is dedicated for ruby 1.8) and wxruby project is no longer developed. So if you need to use ruby 2.0 you are on your own now. But try to ask at http://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/wxruby where some of former wxruby developers are still active and eager to help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still on the battle, I successfully built wxRuby using Ruby 2.3 on linux Ubuntu (Xenial 16.04) and Mint (17 and 18), for both i386 and amd64, testing and using instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789302/install-python-wxgtk2-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [here](http://thesmallestprogrammer.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/installing-wxruby-for-ubuntu.html):

```
# temporary add this source for a complete libwxgtk2.8
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-copies.list
apt update

# install required packages
apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev libglib2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev pangox-1.0-dev build-essential curl git

# install recommended swig version
wget "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/swig/swig/swig-1.3.38/swig-1.3.38.tar.gz?r=&ts=1471028964&use_mirror=ufpr" -O swig-1.3.38.tar.gz
tar zxvf swig-1.3.38.tar.gz
cd swig-1.3.38
./configure
make -j8
make install

# install ruby, using RVM
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm install 2.3.0

# wxRuby
git clone https://github.com/cinnammon/wxRuby-ng
cd ~/wxRuby-ng
export WXRUBY_EXCLUDED=GLCanvas
export WXRUBY_VERSION=2.0.1
# add "Config = RbConfig unless defined?(Config)" to the top of ./rakefile
# and change 'raise "This version of Ruby (#{RUBY_VERSION}) is not supported"'
# on line 38 for "SWIG_MINIMUM_VERSION = '1.3.37'"
rake
# I got some "extern" "static" declaration errors on some files,
# just changed "static" to "extern" and all went well
rake install

# remove source
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-copies.list
apt update
```

I will keep trying to port it to Windows or maybe stick to Linux, but will update this post :)

Comment: Guys, I did it, success on Ruby 3.0.1 :)
Will post results soon