# Is there a tool to convert wxWidgets XRC files to HTML?

Tags: html, xml, wxwidgets, xrc

I have an application with tons of windows (frames and dialogs) made with [wxWidgets XRC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_xrcformat.html). I'm preparing to convert all generated screens to HTML to make an web version, before doing it I would like to know if someone knows a tool for doing so, convert XRC resource to a bunch of DIVs, INPUTs, CHECKBOXes, TABLEs, etc., so I don't need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: maybe you will have a better luck looking at wx-3.1 + wxWebView?

Comment: maybe, but I'm stuck on wx-2.8 with wxruby :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572421/wxwidgets-wxruby-with-ruby-2-0

Comment: can't you compile it yourself?

Comment: just on linux, so far... not windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no such tool exists and, to be honest, I have trouble understanding how one could be written considering that:

1. wxWidgets layout model based on sizers is very different from the typical layout models used on the web, so you would need to find a way to reimplement it in CSS first.
2. wxWidgets provides a much richer set of widgets than standard HTML, so you would also need to have a JavaScript library implementing many of them.

Comment: I need just the basic components, my app is written in Ruby using wxRuby, if I load XRC file using wxWidgets I can pick all elements sizes and positions and replace it with HTML elements, CSS gives it the same look (it is already working). Now I'm trying to generate such windows without loading wxRuby